# Let $X\sim \text{Uniform}(0, \theta)$. What is the distribution of $Y= \theta - X$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

So cdf of $X$ is $F(X\leq x) = \frac{x}{\theta}$.

Let $X = \theta - Y$, subbing it into the cdf we now get:
$$F(\theta - Y \leq x) = \frac{x}{\theta}$$
$$F(-Y \leq x - \theta) = \frac{x}{\theta}$$
$$F(Y\geq \theta - x) = \frac{x}{\theta}$$
$$F(Y\leq \theta - x) = 1 - \frac{x}{\theta}$$
$$=1 - F(X\leq x)$$

This what I came up with but no idea if this is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CDF of $X$ for different cases is really

$$\begin{align*}
\Pr(X \le x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \le 0\\
\frac{x}{\theta}& 0 < x\le \theta\\
1& \theta < x
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

Let $X=\theta - Y$, then the CDF of $Y$ is

$$\begin{align*}
\Pr(Y \le y) &= \Pr(\theta - X \le y)\\
&= \Pr(X \ge \theta - y)\\
&= 1 - \Pr(X < \theta - y)\\
&= 1 -\begin{cases}
0 & \theta - y \le 0\\
\frac{\theta - y}{\theta}& 0 < \theta - y\le \theta\\
1& \theta < \theta - y
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
0 & y < 0\\
\frac{y}{\theta}& 0 \le y < \theta\\
1& \theta \le y
\end{cases}\\
\end{align*}$$

Differentiate $\Pr(Y\le y)$ with respect to $y$ to obtain its PDF.